# Jump to host in remote openvpn network using its CommonName as hostname

Tags: ssh, proxy, openvpn, openssh

There is `server` with public IP and multiple clients from behind NATs, connected to `server` via `openvpn` with `ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt` option in `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`.

All participants of `openvpn` network (`172.16.0.0/16`) has sudo-user `user`. Public key of my local machine is added to `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `~user/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `server` and all the clients. So, using `server` as jump host to `172.16.0.0/16` network I can easily connect to any of the participants of the network by IP with aid of key forwarding (`ForwardAgent yes`).

Issuing certificate/key pairs for `openvpn` clients I assigned meaningful names (therein *CommonName*'s) to them. I'd like to use them as hostnames, passed to `ssh` to connect. To achieve desired I did the following:

`~user/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.root
    ForwardAgent yes
    Compression yes
Host server rserver
    HostName 1.1.1.1
Host client* rclient* 172.16.*
    ProxyCommand ~/.ssh/get_client_ip.bash %h %p
Host client* server
    User user
Host rclient* rserver
    User root
Host 192.168.1.*
    Compression no
```

`~user/.ssh/get_client_ip.bash` (`chmod +x`-ed):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

ssh -T -W $( ssh rserver "awk -F '[.,]' -v OFS='.' '/^"$1",/ { print \$2, \$3, \$4, (\$5 + 2) }' /etc/openvpn/ipp.txt" ):$2 server
```

If I simply type `ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -T -W 172.16.0.4:22 server" 172.16.0.4` (here last `172.16.0.4` (IP of `client1`) really has no any meaning), then connection is established correctly.

If I type `ssh client1`, then I get an error:

> Bad packet length 1349676916.
>
> ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to UNKNOWN port 0: message authentication code incorrect

I checked, that latter is exactly equivalent to former one.

Also bare invokation `bash ~/.ssh/get_client_ip.bash client1 22` establishes connection to `client1`.

How to deal with proxy command enclosed into a bash script? Should I do something additional to redirect standard input and output streams from inside of bash script provided to `ProxyCommand`?

Seems there is a difference between execution command in the middle of the pipe directly or indirectly as a part of the bash script.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with placing proxy script onto server side (there was mostly bash escaping issue) in `~root/.ssh/get_client_ip.bash` (it gives IP for corresponding *CommonName* of `openvpn` client):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

nc $( awk -F ',' '/^'$( sed 's/\./\\&/g' <<< "${1:$3}" )',/ { print $2 }' /etc/openvpn/ipp.txt | awk -F '.' -v OFS='.' '{ print $1, $2, $3, ($4 + 2) }' ) $2
```

Or based on `status server-status.log` (for actually connected clients only):

```
nc $( awk '/ROUTING TABLE/, /GLOBAL STATS/' /etc/openvpn/server-status.log | head --lines=-1 | tail --lines=+3 | awk -F ',' '/,'$( sed 's/\./\\&/g' <<< "${1:$3}" )',/ { print $1 }' ) $2
```

And slightly modified `~user/.ssh/config` on my local machine:

```
Host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.root
    ForwardAgent yes
    Compression yes
Host server rserver
    HostName server
Host rclient* rserver
    User root
Host client* server
    User user
Host rclient*
    ProxyCommand ssh rserver bash ~root/.ssh/get_client_ip.bash %h %p 1
Host client*
    ProxyCommand ssh rserver bash ~root/.ssh/get_client_ip.bash %h %p 0
Host 172.16.*
    ProxyCommand ssh -T -W %h:%p server
Host 192.168.1.*
    Compression no
```